# AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items' KivyMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivymd

I made a chat app but it was command line so I wanted to add some gui to it and after I started making app use ScreenManager the error start occurring.

Here is python code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
import socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        s.connect(("192.168.41.20", 5002))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    class LoginScreen(Screen):
        pass


    class MainScreen(Screen):
        pass


    class SettingScreen(Screen):
        pass


    class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
        pass


    class MainApp(MDApp):
        def build(self):
            return Builder.load_file('kivy.kv')

        def logger(self):
            self.root.ids.welcome_label.text = ('Hello ' + self.root.ids.user.text + '!')
            s.send(bytes('#u'+self.root.ids.user.text, 'utf-8'))
            s.send(bytes('#p'+self.root.ids.password.text, 'utf-8'))

        def clear(self):
            self.root.ids.user.text = ""
            self.root.ids.welcome_label.text = "WELCOME"
            self.root.ids.password.text = ""


    MainApp().run()
```

And here is my kivymd .kv code:

```
WindowManager:
    LoginScreen:
    MainScreen:
    SettingScreen:     

<LoginScreen>:
    name: "login"
    Widget:
        MDCard:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 300, 400
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y":0.5 }
            elevation: 10
            padding: 25
            spacing: 25
            orientation: "vertical"

            MDLabel:
                id: welcome_label
                text: "BALCOME!"
                halign: 'center'
                font_size: 40
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                padding_y: 15
            MDTextFieldRound:
                id: user
                hint_text: "username"
                icon_right: "account"
                width: 200
                size_hint_x: None
                font_size: 18
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            
            MDTextFieldRound:
                id: password
                hint_text: "password"
                icon_right: "eye-off"
                width: 200
                size_hint_x: None
                font_size: 18
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                password: True

            MDRoundFlatButton:
                text: "LOGIN"
                font_size: 12
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                on_press: app.logger()
                on_release: app.root.current = "main"           
            MDRoundFlatButton:
                text: "CLEAR"
                font_size: 12
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                on_press: app.clear()

            Widget:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 10

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    MDRoundFlatButton:
        text: "Get LOst"
        pos_hint: {"center_y: 0.5"}

<SettingScreen>:
    name: "satt"
    MDRoundFlatButton:
        text: "Get Lost"
        pos_hint: {"center_y: 0.5"}
```

And when I run it this error comes:

```
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items' error occurring when I trying to run my code.
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the python code as it is syntactically incorrect and indentation is important in python. Also: include the full stack trace of the error otherwise we have to guess which part of the code is causing the problem.